# Identifying user by browser agent details?

Tags: java, http

I understand that this kind of identification cannot be 100% accurate, but example usage would be internet poll, to detect users that have already voted. Is user detection possible with browser sent details? And what kind of information I can get from browser with every request? If I add IP address or location for example town to this, then identification would be more accurate. Are there any possible downsides I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the research the EFF has conducted, to identify visitors using default browser-transported information - but no cookies.
[Here's the link for Panopticlick.](http://panopticlick.eff.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on such information.

As I'm sure you are aware all of this information can be **easily** forged. As you can specify any request header at will (the request header contains IP, location, browser etc.).

You can use it as a poll, but you should keep in mind that the poll will never be 100% accurate.

If you want to know where the user is from make him authenticate in the site with a valid e-mail and set a cookie on his browser.

Another way to check a user's identity/location is using a paid identity validation service like [URU](http://www.uru.co.uk/id3check/) for instance. Even this however is never 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

ip + location is not a good thing. Much of internet users are behind firewalls/NAT's/proxy's.

Your best best is long term [persistent cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).